# ASP.NET MVC html writer bug?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, runatserver

It's probably a bug. Steps to reproduce:

(1) Create a ASP.NET MVC 3 project (ASPX view engine)

(2) Go to the Models folder and create a new simple model

```
namespace MvcApp.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public static string MyString = "foo";        
    }
}
```

(3) Modify the `web.config` file, add the namespace of the models, so that you can use models in your views.

```
      ....
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcApp.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

(4) Go to `/Shared/Site.Master`, modify the `<head>` section.

```
<head runat="server"> 
    <title><%: MyModel.MyString %><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" rel="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" />
    <script src="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" />
</head>
```

Note `runat="server"` attribute of head.

(5) Run it, and see the source code of the page. I think you will get(unnecessary spaces are removed):

```
<head id="Head1">
   <title>foo Index</title>
   <link href="&lt;%: MyModel.MyString %>" rel="&lt;%: MyModel.MyString %>" />
   <script src="foo" />
</head>
```

Something interesting:

a. All attributes of `link` tag aren't evaluated correctly. it looks like being encoded? While the same expressions in `title` and `script` are correct.

b. Change the 3rd line to this:

```
<link href="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" rel="<%: string.Format("{0}", "foo") %>" />
```

OR

```
<link href="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" rel="<%: "foo" %>" />
```

You will get everything correct(even `href` is correct!).

c. `head` without `runat="server"` is always correct.

I think it's a bug when rendering views to html texts. It's really a nightmare to check the source code and try to find the bug. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is that ASP.NET Server control never convert <% %> tags. Since your Head contains runat="server", then ASP.NET Web Form Engine takes some interenal decision for every child control whether to make it a web server control or not.

Put this

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
<title><%: MyModel.MyString %><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link id="link1" href="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" rel="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" />
<link id="link2" href="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" rel="<%: string.Format("{0}", "foo") %>" /><%sa %>
<script src="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" />
</head>

<script src="<%: MyModel.MyString %>" />
```

Now carefully check ***Show Complete Compilation Source:***

Comment: More than that, I think that's a non relevant problem - if it can be ever be considered a problem at all. Why sticking to the aspx syntax and the "runat=server" stuff, which is legacy from webforms, when we have native Razor designed for Mvc, and way better in every single aspect?

Comment: @Matteo Mosca: It makes sense to use `runat="server"` in ASP.NET MVC. Otherwise how can we use master pages with `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder />`?

Comment: Seems like you read only half of my comment. I was talking about Razor. You don't use <asp:> tags in Razor, it has a different (and totally better) syntax. You still have concepts like masterpages etc just in a different and more elegant way.